# dynamically add rows to a table with java code

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I hope someone can help me here...
I want to add rows to a table dynamically with a for Loop. This is just for example. But when I test it, the Screen where the table should be showed is empty. I don't know where the Problem is, it just Shows nothing.

Here is my Code:

```
private void setElementsList() {
    TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        // Creation row
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 70));
        tableRow.setPadding(0,0,0,8);

        LinearLayout Newrowlayout =new LinearLayout(this);
        Newrowlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,5));
        Newrowlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        Newrowlayout.setBackgroundColor(16746559);

        // Creation textView
        TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
        text2.setText("Order ID: ");
        text2.setTextSize(21);
        text2.setTextColor(16508374);
        text2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text2.setPadding(0,0,2,0);
        text2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // Creation textView
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        text.setTextSize(21);
        text.setTextColor(16508374);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.setPadding(2,0,10,0);
        text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        // Creation textView
        TextView text3 = new TextView(this);
        text3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 3));

        // Creation  button
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(">");
        button.setTextSize(30);
        button.setTextColor(16508374);
        button.setBackgroundColor(16746559);
        button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(70,70));
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        // Creation textView
        TextView text4 = new TextView(this);
        text4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 3));

        // Creation textView
        TextView text5 = new TextView(this);
        text5.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text5.setBackgroundColor(16741149);
        text5.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));

        Newrowlayout.addView(text2);
        Newrowlayout.addView(text);
        tableRow.addView(Newrowlayout);
        tableRow.addView(text3);
        tableRow.addView(button);
        tableRow.addView(text4);
        tableRow.addView(text5);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    }
}
```

If you Need further Details plz ask.

Best regards
domidoof

Comment: Do you want to insert rows in sqlite?

Comment: And why are you creating TextViews inside loop which run 5 time and every time it creates same and same and same again same textview? What is your intention?

Comment: this is just for example. In my Code I want to Loop through an String Array and set the textview with the string in the Array.